# mysql Trying to select latest timestamp only

Tags: mysql, join, timestamp, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to join 2 tables and select the latest timestamp only and the field values associated with that latest timestamp

Data tables:

device_count

```
id  device_name     platform    version     timestamp
1   abc             123         x           2013-12-30
2   abc             123         y           2014-01-01
3   def             345         x           2013-12-30
```

device_list

```
id      device_name     Network     Division    Market
2657    def             a           f           d
2656    abc             a           b           c
```

The desired result should be

```
device_name     platform    version     network     division    market  timestamp
abc             123         y           a           b           c       2014-01-01
def             345         x           a           f           d       2013-12-30
```

I have used the following query but I'm not getting the correct results

```
SELECT
device_count.device_name,
device_count.platform,
device_count.version,
Max(device_count.`timestamp`),
device_list.Network,
device_list.Division,
device_list.Market
FROM
device_count
INNER JOIN device_list ON device_count.device_name = device_list.Device_Name
GROUP BY
device_count.device_name,
device_count.platform,
device_count.version,
device_list.Network,
device_list.Division,
device_list.Market
```

It results in

```
device_name     platform    version     network     division    market  timestamp
abc             123         x           a           b           c       2013-12-30
abc             123         y           a           b           c       2014-01-01
def             345         x           a           f           d       2013-12-30
```

The first record should not be included. I only want the version and platform values from the latest timestamp (record id 2)

Comment: You are grouping by the `version` and `network` numbers, so you will get every one in the output.

Answer (score 0):

try subquery:

```
SELECT
device_count.device_name,
device_count.platform,
device_count.version,
Max(device_count.`timestamp`),
device_list.Network,
device_list.Division,
device_list.Market
FROM
device_count DC
INNER JOIN device_list ON device_count.device_name = device_list.Device_Name
inner join 
    (select device_name, max(timestamp) timestamp
    from device_count
    group by device_name) as DC on DC.timestamp = device_count.timestamp and DC.device_name=device_count.device_name
```

Comment: I did try to just use group by device_name and I get the correct latest timestamp but the version is incorrect. I get the version x from record 1 and timestamp from record 2 when all I want is record 2 and 3

Comment: I edited the query, and changed it from a group by to a subquery.  Try that out.

Comment: I tried the subquery but its not working due to unknown column device_count.device_name. I tired to hack it together and now get subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: I've made another edit, this one supplants the WHERE with an additional INNER JOIN to a subquery that aggregates the device_names with the highest timestamp.  I tested this on SQL Server, and it might just work on mysql.

Comment: I still have the same issue. Unknown column 'device_count.device_name' in 'field list'. Seems to be declaring the table as DC in the from statement is causing the problem

Comment: It may be that mysql wants "AS DC" to alias the inner join table.  See new edit.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to match to a subselect:

```
SELECT
  device_count.device_name,
  device_count.platform,
  device_count.version,
  device_count.`timestamp`,
  device_list.Network,
  device_list.Division,
  device_list.Market
FROM
  device_count
INNER JOIN 
  device_list 
ON device_count.device_name = device_list.Device_Name
WHERE device_count.`timestamp` = (
    SELECT MAX(dc2.`timestamp`)
    FROM
      device_count AS dc2
    WHERE
      dc2.device_name =  device_count.device_name
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Turophile. This does work however on the real data set it takes over 7 mins to complete. device_list contains ~2500 records and device_count contains ~40000. Any way to improve the performance?

Comment: Is there an index on `device_name` in both tables?